# Best way to apply Soft Body to multiple floating meshes that are parented?

Tags: constraints, parent, soft-body, vertex-parent

I have a mesh like the below and I'm wanting to apply soft body physics to it, but to have the parts remain 'connected' — I've tried vertex parenting, rigging etc. but none of it seems to work, I'm definitely missing something or not doing something right — even using constraints didn't seem to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you want to keep the gap between each part?

Comment: @moonboots yes! that is exactly what I want to achieve, I don't mind if there's some movement but to keep the overall shape would be nice, thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: you could use a proxy object (which is connected as soft body) and then parent yours to that proxy object. Is there any reason why you cannot join your meshes one object?

Comment: @Chris I've not heard about proxy objects, would you be able to point me in the right direction of how this would work? And they were under one object to begin with but as a soft body the separate parts still went their own way?

Comment: that's exactly what moonboots does. You don't use your original (high poly mesh) to make a simulation because your computer would start to burn, but use an easy proxy (low poly) mesh to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a cage around the flower object (here I display it as wireframe, you'll need to make it invisible in render of course), give it the *Soft Body* simulation (*Cloth* should work as well), remove the *Soft Body* from your flower, give it *Mesh Deform* modifier with the cage as *Object*, click on the modifier's *Bind* button:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for putting in the time to help me out! What's the fastest way to make a cage given the model I have? I could grow and remesh the parts until they're one part?

Comment: You need to make a simplified version of your current object, either you start from scratch, or you duplicate your object, simplify it, make some bridges between the different parts... The cagemust be slightly bigger than the original, it must encompass it in order to work. A high-resolution cage would give a better simulation but it would also be more tedious to calculate so try to stay as low-poly as possible